# bat file read from cfg file

Tags: batch-file, configuration-files

I have cfg file :
ini.cfg

```
[General]
ENB=ENB205; 
HostIP=127.0.0.1;

[Configuration]
bcem=bcem1;
blade=blade2;
```

and bat file : ini.bat

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

set v=C:\LTE\CI\workspace\config\ini.cfg

for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('find "arg_1=" %v%') do (
    echo fiibar=%%a
)
```

Within the bat file I am able to retrieve the content of ini.cfg. But what I need is the value of each key (i need ENB205 abd 127.0.0.1) to be stored in variable).

Could anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

set v=C:\LTE\CI\workspace\config\ini.cfg

for /F "usebackq eol=[ tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("%v%") do (
    set "%%a"
)
set E
```

This will set the values with the ending `;`. Do need to strip them?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your code is working and return ENB=ENB205 . What I need is EB205 to be stored in variable. I m sorry if that was not clear. And I have question : why does it display sth thourgh command prompt without command echo?

Comment: @user3922604 - yes.Variable is EBN and the value is ENB205 - this is the output of `set E` command. You can access your variable with `%ENB%` or `echo %ENB%`

Answer (score 0):

This script will store the desired variables:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN (ini.cfg) DO (
    SET line=%%a
    IF "!line:~0,4!"=="ENB=" SET enb=!line:~4!
    IF "!line:~0,7!"=="HostIP=" SET host=!line:~7!
)
SET enb=%enb:;=%
SET host=%host:;=%
ECHO ENB: %enb%
ECHO Host: %host%
```